# jQuery rotate not working in IE7 and IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

i cant get even a simple rotate to work for IE7 or 8:

```
$('#square').rotate(45);

#square{
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

the above code does nothing in ie7&8, but works fine in 9+ and other browsers

how can i get this to work? or an alternative?

Comment: Is your script at the end of the body or wrapped in a document ready handler? If the element is not on the page when `.rotate()` is called, you won't see any results...

Comment: hey, yes it is - the above code isn't in order, just to show what's there

Comment: Could you try adding `console.log($('#square').length);` to see if the element exists. Maybe there's a typo with the ID...

Comment: Not enough code to reproduce. Are you getting any JS erros? Show us a reproducible test case - i.e. JSFiddle, or a link to your page.

Answer (score 0):

To rotate in IE7 you need this

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476); /* IE6,IE7 */

So maybe you need something like this:

```
$("#square").css("filter", "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)");
```

Answer (score -1):

The plugin does not offer IE7 support.

I recommend using the Gsap animation library. It has a nice jQuery wrapper to help with newcomers http://www.greensock.com/jquery-gsap-plugin/ and is backwards compatible down to ie7 with almost all of its features.

Comment: On the [homepage](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) for the plugin: _"Internet Explorer 6.0 >"_...

Comment: "Last release: v.2.3 11.07.2013" yeah because a year old plugin is still relevant

Comment: It's what the OP is using. Unless you're found a different one jQuery Rotate. The point is, the statement _"The plugin does not offer IE 7 support"_ is wrong...

Comment: Ok, my bad there. Didn't take the time to read, but i did test and it doesn't work, so my error aside, it's broken.